# Проблема с кодировкой

Tags: phpmyadmin, sql

Скажите, у меня есть сайт http://free-visitor.hut4.ru/ - там внизу слева есть, раздел новостей, так вот почему-то там вопросики.. хотя на денвере всё ОК, базу не менял. Вот сама база

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно у вас на денвере файл сохранен в одной кодировке а там в другой.можете просто найти файл который отвечает за эти новости на phpmyadmin и изменить в нем кодировку